# pyqt5 normalize a vector

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5

Assume I have 2 points in Pyqt5.

```
QtCore.QPoint(200,200)
QtCore.QPoint(400,400)
```

Now, I would like to normalize this vector points. Is there a way to find the normalized vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QVector2D:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

A = QtCore.QPoint(200,200)
B = QtCore.QPoint(400,400)

res = QtGui.QVector2D(B-A).normalized()
print(res)
```

Output:

```
PyQt5.QtGui.QVector2D(0.7071067690849304, 0.7071067690849304)
```